# jQuery ajax and SQL query not displaying as expected on HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I have a an ajax function that is not displaying properly on my html page. I have included a screenshot of the error here:

[image: Screen shot]

**What is happening:** The ajax function is POSTed to my PHP file where an SQL Query is ran. The stagename of the musician is searched in my database and the real name of the artist is ultimately returned from the ajax function and sent my HTML page in a div with id="#namers". When I click on an artists name, that name is stored in a variable, sent into the ajax function and sql query and the returned name value is displayed.

**The Problem:** 
The page comes up, shows the artists name (duplicated) but then 2-3 seconds later, the element disappears entirely. In the GIF I am clicking only once and the artists name. Each click event triggers the ajax function and subsequently, an SQL query.

**What I would like:**
I would like the name of the artist to appear only once and I would like the name to be statically displayed on the page. I want to stop the div from disappearing. When I click on an artists name, I want the element with their real name to be displayed until another artist is clicked on. Each name only needs to be loaded to the site once per visit.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#namers').hide();
$('#prf').hide();
$('.artists').click(function () {
    $('.mainpage').hide();
    $('#prf').show();
    }); //when .artists is clicked   
 $('li').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    $('#prf').attr("class",name);
    $('#pic').attr("class",name);
    $('#info').attr("class",name);        
    $.post("ajax-name.php", {name: name}, function( html ) { 
        $('#namers').html(html);
    }) //POST function
    $('#namers').show();
 }); //when 'li' clicked
}); //document.ready
```

PHP:

```
<?php
        //PDO
        $rname = $_POST['name'];                        
        try {    
        $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=myhost;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query="SELECT realname FROM artistmaster WHERE stagename = :name";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array("name"=>$rname));             
        $result=$stmt->fetchAll();            
        foreach($result[0] as $child) {    
            echo $child . "<br />"; }
        }
        catch(PDOExeception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}              
        ?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>       

</head>
<body>
        <div class="header"><h1></h1></div>      

    <div class="mainpage">
        <h1>Get Curious. Click an artists to get started. Have fun! :)</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="prf" class="profile">
            <div id ="info" class="basicinfo">                  
                <div id="pic" class="artistphoto">Artist photo here</div>
                <div class="artistname">Name(s):<div id="namers"></div></div>
                <div id="hometown" class="hometown">Hometown:</div>           
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="leftpanel">
        <ul class="artists" >
            <li>Aly and Fila</li>
            <li>Andrew Rayel</li>
            <li>Arnej</li>
            <li>Avicii</li>
            <li>Basenectar</li>
            <li>Borgeous</li>
            <li>Bryan Kearney</li>
            <li>Caked Up</li>
            <li>Cash Cash</li>
            <li>Coone</li>
            <li>David Guetta</li>
            <li>Dimitri Vegas and Like Mike</li>
            <li>Diplo</li>
            <li>Dirtcaps</li>
            <li>DVBBS</li>
            <li>DYRO</li>
            <li>ETC! ETC!</li>
            <li>Ferry Corsten</li>
            <li>Henry Fong</li>
            <li>John Digweed</li>
            <li>Jordan Suckley</li>
            <li>Kaskade</li>
            <li>Le Castle Vania</li>
            <li>Martin Garrix</li>
            <li>M4sonic</li>
            <li>Makj</li>
            <li>Mat Zo</li>
            <li>Morgan Page</li>
            <li>Myon and Shane 54</li>
            <li>New World Sound</li>
            <li>Nicky Romero</li>
            <li>Orjan Nilsen</li>
            <li>Paris Blohm</li>
            <li>Pete Tong</li>
            <li>Richie Hawtin</li>
            <li>Romeo Blanco</li>
            <li>Skrillex</li>
            <li>Simon Patterson</li>                
            <li>Steve Aoki</li>
            <li>Swanky Tunes</li>
            <li>Tiesto</li>
            <li>TJR</li>
            <li>Woflpack</li>
            <li>Yves V</li>
            <li>Zedd</li>
        </ul>       
        </div>
            <div class="footer">
        <h1>footer</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what exactly are you clicking, there are no `.artists` or LI's in the HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo I had initially excluded that part of my code due to its size, but I've updated my question to now include all of my HTML code.